# BluetoothServerSocket.accept() never returns when Bluetooth is disabled

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using `BluetoothServerSocket.accept()` to accept incoming Bluetooth connections. It is known that `BluetoothServerSocket.accept()` blocks until a incoming connection or until error (throwing `IOException`). Everything works fine, except following: when Bluetooth is disabled  after calling `BluetoothServerSocket.accept()`, no exception occurs. As a result, the thread is blocked forever until `close()` is called.
That makes no sense to me, as there is absolutelty no way Bluetooth adapter can accept a connection when it off.

There is an ugly way to solve that with `BluetoothSocket.accept(int timeout)`, and it is also possible to listen to `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` event, and call `close()` on the accept thread when it is off. But that sounds too hackish for such a simple event.

Is there a more clean way to return from `BluetoothServerSocket.accept()` after Bluetooth adapter is disabled?

Comment: It makes little sense to call accept() when Bluetooth is dsabled, either.

Comment: Sure. But Bluetooth is disabled _after_ accept() is called.